# Graph API: Posting feed with youtube video in source does not show images on mobile

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, youtube

I tried to share a link in my iPhone app through Graph API's feed.

The link points back to my app.

I also wanted to share a picture and source. The picture is provided by me and the source is a youtube link.

I followed the following guideline for youtube link [Posting an embedded video link using the Facebook Graph API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/q/5227607/379604)

It works but only for desktop, where it display my picture and the play video button.

On Facebook iOS app, it only display my link. hiding my picture and source.

How can I get the desktop behavior on the Facebook iOS app?

Comment: now the problem has also appeared on Desktop with the new Facebook Timeline feature.

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't a solution per-se but I've filed a bug report on Facebook. You can find the link here - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/180280085419619. It might help if you went and clicked the links saying you could reproduce the issue.

Comment: Done! I hope they fix it soon! :D